# Adding a line on geom_bar with tidyverse in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

overflowers,

I want to add my average arrivals as geom_line per hour on a geom_bar. This is an example synthetic data I have, a table called df_avg_occ .

```
structure(list(hour = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                        "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
                        "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), 
               average = c(2.61835748792271, 2.11352657004831, 
                           1.71497584541063, 1.40338164251208, 
                           1.15700483091787, 1.86376811594203, 
                           1.83574879227053, 1.83478260869565, 
                           1.1256038647343,  1.7512077294686, 
                           2.4951690821256, 2.08695652173913, 
                           3.52898550724638,3.85990338164251, 
                           3.96376811594203, 4.00968523002421, 
                           3.9225181598063, 3.96610169491525, 
                           3.89588377723971, 3.95883777239709, 
                           3.81884057971014, 3.71497584541063, 4.5, 
                           3.08454106280193), 
              avg_arrivals = c(2.71428571428571,  1.91666666666667, 
                               1.30612244897959, 1.38, 1.85106382978723, 
                               1.79583333333333, 1.14285714285714, 
                               2.93877551020408, 3.33333333333333, 
                               4.82456140350877, 6.03448275862069, 
                               6.47368421052632, 6.53448275862069, 
                               6.48275862068965, 5.77586206896552, 
                               6.49122807017544, 6.37931034482759, 
                               5.89655172413793, 5.70689655172414, 
                               6.17241379310345, 5.77586206896552, 
                               4.27586206896552, 4.1551724137931, 
                               2.7719298245614)), 
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
              row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Note: this is not a real data.

And this is what I have plotted up to now using tidyverse - ggplot2

```
plt_occupancy <- ggplot(tbl_avg_occ, aes(x = hour, average, group = hour))
plt_occupancy + geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
                         alpha=0.7, width = 0.50, fill= "yellow4") +
xlim("0", "1" , "2" , "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
     "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22","23") +
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 5.5)) +
theme_bw()+ 
labs(title = "Gabriel Burcea Hospital: Hourly ED Occupancy, 3rd of March to 
              27th of April 2016",
     subtitle = "Average Hourly ED Occupancy, n, by Hour of the day.
Note: results are intended for management information only",
     y = "Average occupancy, n", x = "Hour of the day", 
     caption = "Source: Gabriel Burcea ) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 21, b = 0, l = 
      0)),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10))
```

Comment: You will get more answers if you are more specific about what you are trying to do. Try posting a picture of what you have, and a picture of what you want (draw if necessary).

Comment: Hello Rasmus, to be honest, I do not know how to post pictures here. Nevertheless, I have added the code for my plot. Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a dodged bar plot

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -hour) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour, v, fill=k)) + 
   geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Or without transforming the data.frame you can add `avg_arrivals` as points

```
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(hour))) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:24)+
  geom_col(aes(y=average, fill="my bars")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=avg_arrivals)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=avg_arrivals, group=1, color="my lines")) +
  scale_fill_manual("",values="yellow") + 
  scale_color_manual("",values = 1)
```

[image]

Instead of `geom_line` you can also use `geom_path(aes(y=avg_arrivals))`

Comment: Hello Jimbou, I want to add this as a geom_line - the avg_arrivals as a line, and the average as a geom_bar.

Comment: you are a star, Jimbou! thanks a lot mate! Yet, a bit careful with the sequence of the hours during the day. Nevertheless, it is really good.

Comment: @GabrielBurcea please see my edits for the hour issue.

Comment: yes, as you can see 24 is left out, that means that breaks are from 0:23?

Comment: yes, feel free to change this to whatever you want.

Comment: Hello Jimbou, is there a way I can add a legend having in mind the bars and lines are different colour?

Comment: well, lets say the line is black and the bars are yellow4. Then on the legend the line shall appear black and only one bar as yellow. Does it make sense?

Comment: how I plot in stackoverflow? I googled it and cannot. Hard to deal with stackoverflow. I am learning though

Comment: @ Jimbou - can you please use my example and add that to my example? I have used you ideas to my plot.